# Image hyperlink not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I designed a page and put a hyperlinked image in the header.

[image]

In the picture above, I want the entire image 'Vivo city' to be clickable and to go to a certain hyperlink. But actually only a small part of it is clickable.

I am not sure why the entire image is not clickable.

```
<a  href="index" >
<img   src="../../assets/img/logo_white.png"  width="110px"  height="51px" /></a>
```

You can check my website here - http://107.167.189.78/codeigniter/index.php/web/

The image link is inside a Bootstrap navbar. Please help me find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: As what  @j08691 said and also post the relevant CSS.

Comment: Inspect elements and see what is overlapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because its sister element `.navbar-collapse` is positioned partially above it:

[image]

Edited: To be fair, this is the answer to the question "what is wrong?". The follow-up question "...and how do I fix it?" is answered by Serlite in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32186168/2377479)

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I was investigating for a long time, but didnt think this was the cause. The issue is fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*(Note: I know the initial question of "what is wrong" has been answered - but felt it would be of value to explain a bit and show a solution too.)*

As noted by danielaKay, your navigation menu next to the logo is causing the overlapping issue. Currently you're using relative positioning to move the menu to the right:

```css
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 55px;
}
```

In combination with your `float` on the logo, this is causing the menu to partially cover the logo and make it unclickable. Consider floating the menu in the same direction the logo is already floated, and just add a margin to the left instead (replacing your relative positioning):

```css
{
    margin-left: 55px;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Unfortunately, it's difficult to demonstrate this fix without recreating your entire site, since you haven't provided a minimal, complete, and verifiable example in your original question. Please be sure to do that in the future, as it would be a great benefit to readers of this question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. @Serlite

Comment: I have fixed the issue now. Cheers.

Comment: Great, glad I could help out.